# Nonsmooth version of Hopf boundary point lemma

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, elliptic-pde, regularity

Let
$$
Lu=-a_{ij}(x)\partial_{ij}u+b_i(x)\partial_i u
$$
be a uniformly elliptic operator, with $A(x)=(a_{ij}(x))$ positive-definite.
Here I'm only considering smooth coefficients, and the domain $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^d$ is as smooth as needed (but bounded).
In one of its elementary versions, the classical [Hopf boundary point lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_lemma) states that if $u\in C^2(\Omega)\cap C^1(\bar\Omega)$ is a supersolution
$$
Lu\geq 0
$$
and attains a minimum point at $x_0\in \partial\Omega$ then
$$
\partial_\nu u(x_0)<0,
$$
where $\nu=\nu(x_0)$ is the outer normal to $\partial\Omega$ at $x_0$.
In other words, the supersolution must grow linearly inside the domain close to a boundary minimum point.
There are various possible extensions, in particular $\nu$ can be any outward pointing direction, and $\Omega$ can have corners.

**Question:**

> Can one say anything about the behaviour of $u$ at any such boundary minimum point, assuming only that $u\in C^2(\Omega)\cap C(\bar\Omega)$?

The key point here being the lack of $C^1$ regularity up to the boudnary.
I need this typically for a singular eigenvalue problem, where in fact I am trying to retrieve some information on a principal eigenpair $(\lambda_0,u_0(x))$ to a singular problem of the form
$$
Lu_0=\frac{1}{\theta(x)}\lambda_0 u_0.
$$
My weight $\theta(x)$ is a given, smooth function that is positive inside $\Omega$ but vanishes linearly, typically $\theta(x)=\operatorname {dist}_{\partial\Omega}(x)$.

Some probabilistic arguments tell me for free that $u_0\geq 0$ is nontrivial and $\lambda_0>0$, with $u_0$ being moreover $C^2$ in the interior and continuously vanishing at the boundary.
I need to show that the vanishing is linear.
Of course Hopf's lemma immediately pops up to mind, but I really cannot guarantee the $C^1$ regularity up to the boundary (and all my attempts in that direction have failed so far).
Actually for my purposes it would suffice to get
$$
c\operatorname{dist}_{\partial\Omega}(x)\leq u_0(x) \leq C\operatorname{dist}_{\partial\Omega}(x)
$$
in a neighborhood of $x_0$.
Has anyone ever heard of something like that? For example, sandwiching $u_0$ between two local lower/upper barriers vanishing linearly would do the trick, but I dont' really know how to do that.

*Final kinky comment:* to tell the truth, really, I'm working in the one-dimensional interval $\Omega=(0,1)$. But the question is so natural that I felt I had to write it in a slightly more general framework. So, if anyone has a specific 1D trick I'll be happy too!

Comment: @LSpice: thanks for the tex editing, I am indeed too lazy for real operatorname without macros (mathbb R is about as far as I usually go...) As for the text: yes, I really meant kinky, because I'm (poorly) trying to trick people into the question, whereas it's really a 1D ODE in the end. By all means feel free to edit if you feel it appropriate.

Comment: I wouldn't want to edit to change meaning.  Since the question has been answered anyway, I have deleted my comment.

Comment: Leo, perhaps you'll find something useful also in this paper by Alvarado, R.; Brigham, D.; Maz’ya, V.; Mitrea, M.; Ziadé, E. "On the regularity of domains satisfying a uniform hour-glass condition and a sharp version of the Hopf-Oleinik boundary point principle" Journal of Mathematical Sciences (New York) 176, No. 3, 281-360 (2011), [MR2839047](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR2839047), [Zbl 1290.35046](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1290.35046).

Comment: it deals with a generalization of the interior sphere condition and offers some sharp results.

Comment: Indeed this looks quite interesting to me, thanks @DanieleTampieri

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is just the comment following Lemma 3.4 of Gilbarg and Trudinger (specifically equation 3.11).

I should add that lowering the regularity of the boundary seems like a harder problem (and is I think false in the case of a square).  GT require an interior sphere condition.  L. Rosales (see for instance [Generalizing Hopf’s Boundary Point Lemma](https://doi.org/10.4153/CMB-2017-074-6)) seems to have the best results in this direction.

Comment: Oh, great, this is exactly what I need. Much appreciated!